# Django rest framework non-model serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, serialization, django-serializer

Let's say I have a model like

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    kwargs = models.TextField()
```

where the `kwargs` field is usually a JSON string, representing a dictionary of keyword arguments, e.g. `'{"X": 1, "Y": 2}'`.  It's not practical to modify this model, as it's a model belonging to a 3rd party app, and modifying the field would probably require a fork and other changes in the code.

Now, I'm using `django-rest-framework` to provide and endpoint for creating/updating/listing/deleting instances of `MyModel`, and I have a serializer something like:

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('kwargs',)
```

to facilitate this. This all works OK, but for various reasons the user *does not* want to have manually enter the JSON dump string of the kwargs, i.e. manually entering `'{"X": 1, "Y": 2}'` in the text box or passing that manually built string. They'd rather be able to individually pass `X` and `Y` to the API.

How can I achieve this with a serializer? In other words how can I create a serializer with non-model fields offered to the user, but which get dumped/combined into a JSON string on update/create and mapped to the `kwargs` model instance field accordingly.

Comment: I am confused. You have only one field, which happens to be a text field, but you want to use a serializer to build your json based on user input?

Comment: The model being serialized has one field (well at least in this minimal example), but I would like the serialized to have multiple fields, e.g. X, Y the input of which gets combined into a string representing a JSON dictionary, which is then stored in the model instance's kwargs field as text.

Comment: You could create a serializer with all your fields, run serializer.is_valid() and convert the validated data to a json with json.dumps().

Answer (score 7):

You don't have to make your serializer a ModelSerializer if you don't want to (maybe you already realize this, but I know I didn't at first), you can just inherit from serializers.Serializer, with the fields you want. Something like

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    x = serializers.IntegerField()
    y = serializers.IntegerField()
```

Then you just set up your view to use this serializer, grab the data from it and create/update the model in the view.